# Yii2 custom rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii2

I create small site with Yii2 basic, and I have problem, I search every times and not resolved this, I try rewrite with .htaccess file but not success.

My site have more category get from database example: house-building, car, job, computer, travel.....
I would like user click on category example: http://example.com/house-building => it access category/index?category=house-building

Current, my config/web.php as bellow.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        #'suffix'=>'.html',
        'rules' => array(
            ''=>'site/index',
            '/login.html'=>'/users/login',
            '/register.html'=>'/users/create',

            ### End custom url
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ],
```

Can you help me resolved this issues.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule:

```
'<category:\w+>' => 'category/index'
```

Comment: OH, very thanks for your suggest, I use:
'<category:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>'=>'article/index'
and this work.
Cùng là người Việt Nam. hehe.